# How can you define 'λ' as alias for 'lambda' in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, alias

I know that I can create an alias like so:
`(define first car)` i.e. `(first '(a b c))` => `a`
But this won't work for certain keywords, I can't say `(define alias define)` or `(define λ lambda)`
But what I'd like to do is define `λ` as an alias for `lambda` so that I can say:

```
(define add
  (λ args-list
    (apply + args-list)))
```

instead of the usual

```
(define add
  (lambda args-list
    (apply + args-list)))
```

Would appreciate it if anyone knows how to do this or can point me in the right direction. I am aware that this is out of the box with Racket, but I want to know how this can be implemented, provided that it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a macro

```
(define-syntax λ
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ args body ...)
     (lambda args body ...))))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!